# (ReactJS) Why do changes made in a component by its event handlers remain when the component is re-rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, handler

I'm having a problem in React where if an event handler is triggered in a component, and it changes parts of the component (like style or textContent), those changes don't reset/revert when the component is re-rendered.

More specifics: I want to set up a basic forum/board page where you select a category from one drop down, and then select a topic from the second drop-down. Choosing the topic will fill an array with "post" objects, and the array is used to render the list of posts for it below. There's a search bar at the top which also renders posts through an array of post objects if it finds matches.

The posts that get rendered feature thumbs-up, thumbs-down and trash can icons. The thumbs icons have an onClick event that changes a "likes: " text on that post, while the trash can icon "deletes" the post (changes its display to none; only for visual effect).

**UPDATED 12/7/22**
The problem is, if I increase the likes/dislikes on a post or "delete" it and search a term, if a post from the results occupies the same position as the post I liked/disliked/deleted, the like/dislike number or the "deleted" effect remains and applies to that new post.

In other words, say the display shows 3 posts at first. The second post has 4 likes. I add a like so it updates to 5. Then I enter a search term that yields 5 posts that will render over the initial 3. By default, the second search result post is supposed to have 20 likes. But it's occupying the same position in the display as the one I modified; so the likes displayed shows 5 instead of 20. Note: The search bar is in a different component, parent to the component with the drop-downs. The component with the drop-downs is parent to the component where the posts display.

I tried:

*Component with search bar (forumData and userData are unrelated)*

```
(...)
function setSearchValue(e){
    if (e.key === "Enter"){
        setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
        setRenderSwitch(!renderSwitch);
    }
  }

    return (
        <>
            <header>
                <h1>Pseudo Forum</h1>
                <input type="text" id="postSearchBox" placeholder="search the entire forum" defaultValue={searchQuery} onKeyUp={setSearchValue}></input>
            </header>
            <section id="middle-section">
                <LeftColumn />
                <CenterColumn threads={forumData} searchQuery={searchQuery} renderSwitch={renderSwitch} />
                <RightColumn threads={forumData} users={userData} />
            </section>
        </>
    );
(...)
```

*Component with drop-downs*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './CenterColumn.css';
import Post from '../PostComponent/Post.jsx';

function CenterColumn(props) {
  const [topics, setTopics] = useState([]);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [topicVal, setTopicVal] = useState("");
  const [categoryVal, setCategoryVal] = useState(0);
  const [reSearch, setReSearch] = useState(false);

  useEffect(function(){
    setCategoryVal("");
    setPosts([]);
    setTopicVal("");
    setTopics([]);
    if (props.searchQuery !== ""){
        let allPosts = [];
        function getAllPosts(){
          let returnArray = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < props.threads.length; i++){
            for (let j = 0; j < props.threads[i].topicList.length; j++){
              for(let k = 0; k < props.threads[i].topicList[j].listPosts.length; k++){
                returnArray.push(props.threads[i].topicList[j].listPosts[k]);
              }
            }
          }

          return returnArray;
        }

        allPosts = getAllPosts();

        let searchResults = allPosts.filter(findResults);

        function findResults(eachPost){
          return (eachPost.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(props.searchQuery.toUpperCase()) > -1);
        }
        setPosts(searchResults);
        setReSearch(!reSearch);
    }

    else{
      setPosts([]);
    }
  }, [props.renderSwitch]);

  function assignTopics(e){
    setCategoryVal(parseInt(e.target.value));
    setPosts([]);
    setTopicVal("");

    setTopics(function(){
      if (e.target.value !== ""){
        return props.threads[(parseInt(e.target.value) - 1)].topicList;
      }
      
      return [];
    });
  }

  function assignPosts(e){
    setTopicVal(e.target.value);
    setPosts(function(){
      if (e.target.value !== ""){
        return props.threads[categoryVal - 1].topicList[(parseInt(e.target.value) -1)].listPosts;
      }

      return [];
    })
  }

  return ( 
        <section id="centerColumn">
              <section id="dropDownSection">
                <section id="categoryPair">
                    <label htmlFor="categoryDropDown">Choose Category</label>
                    <select id="categoryDropDown" onChange={assignTopics} value={categoryVal}>
                      <option value="">Select a Category</option>
                      {
                          props.threads.map(function(category){
                            return (<option value={category.id} key={category.id}>{category.name}</option>)
                      })}
                    </select>
                </section>
                <section id="topicPair">
                    <label htmlFor="topicDropDown">Choose Topic</label>
                    <select id="topicDropDown" onChange={assignPosts} value={topicVal}>
                      <option value="">Select a Thread</option>
                      {
                          topics.map(function(topic){
                            return (<option value={topic.id} key={topic.id}>{topic.topic_title}</option>)
                      })}
                    </select>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section id="postSection">
                {
                  posts.map(function(post){
                    return (<Post post={post} reSearch={reSearch} />)
                })}
              </section>
        </section>
    );
  }
  
  export default CenterColumn;
```

*Component with post display*

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import './Post.css';
import {FaThumbsUp, FaThumbsDown, FaTrashAlt} from 'react-icons/fa';

function Post(props){
    let likeCounterRef = useRef(null);
    let deleteRef = useRef(null);

    function updateLikes(e){
        if (e.currentTarget.className === "thumbsUp"){
            let likesCount = parseInt(likeCounterRef.current.textContent.split(":")[1]);
            likesCount++;
            likeCounterRef.current.textContent= `likes:${likesCount}`;
            
        }
        else if (e.currentTarget.className === "thumbsDown"){
            let likesCount = parseInt(likeCounterRef.current.textContent.split(":")[1]);
            likesCount--;
            likeCounterRef.current.textContent = `likes:${likesCount}`;
        }
    }


    function deletePost(e){
        deleteRef.current.style.display="none";
    }


    return (
        <section className="wholePost" key={props.post.id} ref={deleteRef}>
            <section className="messageArea">
                <p className="message">{props.post.text}</p><p className="likes" ref={likeCounterRef}>likes:{props.post.like}</p><p className="thumbsUp" onClick={updateLikes}><FaThumbsUp style={{color: "green"}} /></p><p className="thumbsDown" onClick={updateLikes}><FaThumbsDown style={{color: "red"}} /></p>
            </section>
            <section className="metadata">
            <p className="author">by:{props.post.author}</p><p className="postDate">{props.post.date}</p><p className="replies">replies:{props.post.replies}</p><p className="trashCan"><FaTrashAlt style ={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={deletePost} /></p>
            </section>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

Expected:
The Post component would be completely re-rendered and the text reset/reverted whenever a different drop-down option is selected (or search term is entered that yields a post in the same position as the modified one). The likes count would reset and deleted posts would reappear.

Instead:
Changes to the likes count on a post carry over to whichever post newly occupies its position. Similarly, if I "delete" a post and change topic, that new topic's post in the same position/order will also be missing.

Outline of images (**UPDATED**):

1 - A list of posts. Didn't click on any likes yet. Likes is at 0 for first one:

[First post in list, Likes 0 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdNFe.png)

2 - Search yields different set of posts. Didn't click on any likes yet. Likes is at 22 for first:

[Different first post, Likes 22 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnPbf.png)

3 - Switched back to displaying first set of posts. Clicked the thumbs up on the first post. Likes is at 1.

[Back to first set of posts, clicked thumbs up and likes is now 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD6Cs.png)

4 - Did previous search to get second set of results again. Look at the likes of the first post here, it went from 22 to 1.

[First post in new set (thus, occupies the same position of the modified post from previous set)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVxac.png)

Comment: Does each post has unique id? If it does, maybe you can try `<Post key={post.id} post={post} reSearch={reSearch} />`. 
Another comment of mine is you shouldn't mutate the HTML content with ref like you did in Post component. Just use `const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0)` and `const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false)`.

Comment: I noticed in the console that it was warning about the key despite the key being set in the component. So I fixed that by a little restructuring and moving the array map function directly into the component. Not only have the console warnings disappeared, one half of the problem I'm facing is solved. I updated my question with this recent development, but in summary, switching between drop-downs correctly re-render the posts now. However, the same issue is still present through the search bar. Please see the question for more details. I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: I also made the change to the post.jsx that you suggested in regards to avoiding ref. I removed its use, replaced with useState.

Comment: Hi, can you update the latest codes? I still there's an issue with keys. `key={props.post.id}` is not quite needed. But keys are needed here `<Post post={post} reSearch={reSearch} />`. I'm not sure if you have updated the codes or not